# Can I use realtime rendering to render images?

Tags: rendering

I wondered wheter there is a way to switch to realtime rendering instead of off-line rendering in blender so it will not take detectable time to render an image?

Comment: You can use *OpenGL Render Active Viewport* in the 3D view header, for stills or animations.

Comment: And how can I save an image from that ?

Comment: For stills just press F3 like any regular render. Animations are saved to the *Output* folder defined in the render panel

Comment: Blender can save [screenshots as well as screencasts](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/editors/info/screenshot.html).